# How to pass Regexp.last_match to a block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, scope, iterator, yield

Is there any way to pass the **last match** (practically `Regexp.last_match`) to a block (iterator) in Ruby?

Here is a sample method as a kind of wrapper of `Srring#sub` to demonstrate the problem. It accepts both the standard arguments and a block:

```
def newsub(str, *rest, &bloc)
  str.sub(*rest, &bloc)
end
```

It works in the standard arguments-only case and it can take a block; however the positional special variable like $1, $2, etc are not usable inside the block.  Here are some examples:

```
newsub("abcd", /ab(c)/, '\1')        # => "cd"
newsub("abcd", /ab(c)/){|m| $1}      # => "d"  ($1 == nil)
newsub("abcd", /ab(c)/){$1.upcase}   # => NoMethodError
```

The reason the block does not work in the same way as `String#sub(/..(.)/){$1}` is I suppose something to do with the scope; the special variables $1, $2 etc are local variables (so is `Regexp.last_match`).

Is there any way to solve this?  I would like to make the method `newsub` work just as `String#sub` does, in the sense $1, $2, etc are usable in the supplied block.

EDIT: According to [some past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550434/using-1-2-etc-global-variables-inside-method-definition), there may not be a way to achieve this…

Comment: This question, imo, deserves upvotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. I think I understand the background exactly now at last – I have posted a fairly comprehensive (though long) answer to summarise it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland In fact I have found a way! I have made a major update in my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way as per the question (Ruby 2).  It is not pretty, and is not quite 100% perfect in all aspects, but does the job.

```
def newsub(str, *rest, &bloc)
  str =~ rest[0]  # => ArgumentError if rest[0].nil?
  bloc.binding.tap do |b|
    b.local_variable_set(:_, $~)
    b.eval("$~=_")
  end if bloc
  str.sub(*rest, &bloc)
end
```

With this, the result is as follows:

```
_ = (/(xyz)/ =~ 'xyz')
p $1  # => "xyz"
p _   # => 0

p newsub("abcd", /ab(c)/, '\1')        # => "cd"
p $1  # => "xyz"
p _   # => 0

p newsub("abcd", /ab(c)/){|m| $1}      # => "cd"
p $1  # => "c"
p _                 # => #<MatchData "abc" 1:"c">

v, _ = $1, newsub("efg", /ef(g)/){$1.upcase}
p [v, _]  # => ["c", "G"]
p $1  # => "g"
p Regexp.last_match # => #<MatchData "efg" 1:"g">
```

#### In-depth analysis

In the above-defined method `newsub`, when a block is given, the local variables $1 etc in the caller's thread are (re)set, after the block is executed, which is consistent with `String#sub`.  However, when a block is not given, the local variables $1 etc are **not** reset, whereas in `String#sub`, $1 etc are always reset regardless of whether a block is given or not.

Also, the caller's local variable `_` is reset in this algorithm.  In Ruby's convention, the local variable `_` is used as a dummy variable and its value should not be read or referred to.  Therefore, this should not cause any practical problems.  If the statement `local_variable_set(:$~, $~)` was valid, no temporary local variables would be needed.  However, it is not, in Ruby (as of Version 2.5.1 at least).  See a comment (in Japanese) by Kazuhiro NISHIYAMA in [[ruby-list:50708]](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-list/50708).

### General background (Ruby's specification) explained

Here is a simple example to highlight Ruby's specification related to this issue:

```
s = "abcd"
/b(c)/ =~ s
p $1     # => "c"
1.times do |i|
  p s    # => "abcd"
  p $1   # => "c"
end
```

The special variables of `$&`, `$1`, `$2`, etc, (related, `$~` (`Regexp.last_match`), `$'` and alike)
work in the local scope.  In Ruby, a local scope inherits the variables of the same names in the parent scope.
In the example above, the variable `s` is *inherited*, and so is `$1`.
The `do` block is *yield*-ed by `1.times`, and the method `1.times` has no control over the variables inside the block except for the block parameters (`i` in the example above; *n.b.*, although `Integer#times` does not provide any block parameters, to attempt to receive one(s) in a block would be silently ignored).

This means a method that *yield*-s a block has no control over `$1`, `$2`, etc in the block, which are local variables (even though they may look like global variables).

#### Case of String#sub

Now, let us analyse how `String#sub` with the block works:

```
'abc'.sub(/.(.)./){ |m| $1 }
```

Here, the method `sub` first performs a Regexp match, and hence the local variables like `$1` are automatically set.  Then, they (the variables like `$1`) are inherited in the block, *because this block is in the same scope as the method "sub"*.  They are **not passed** from `sub` to the block, being different from the block parameter `m` (which is a matched String, or equivalent to `$&`).

For that reason, if the method `sub` is defined in a *different scope* from the block, the `sub` method has no control over local variables inside the block, including `$1`.  A *different scope* means the case where the `sub` method is written and defined with a Ruby code, or in practice, all the Ruby methods except some of those written not in Ruby but in the same language as used to write the Ruby interpreter.

Ruby's [official document (Ver.2.5.1)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-sub) explains in the section of `String#sub`:

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set appropriately.

Correct.  In practice, the methods that can and do set the Regexp-match-related special variables such as $1, $2, etc are limited to some built-in methods, including `Regexp#match`, `Regexp#=~`,  `Regexp#===`,`String#=~`, `String#sub`,  `String#gsub`, `String#scan`,  `Enumerable#all?`, and `Enumerable#grep`.
Tip 1: `String#split` seems to reset `$~` nil always.
Tip 2: `Regexp#match?` and `String#match?` do not update `$~` and hence are much faster.

Here is a little code snippet to highlight how the scope works:

```
def sample(str, *rest, &bloc)
  str.sub(*rest, &bloc)
  $1    # non-nil if matches
end

sample('abc', /(c)/){}  # => "c"
p $1    # => nil
```

Here, `$1` *in the method sample()* is set by `str.sub` in the same scope.  That implies the method `sample()` would not be able to (simply) refer to `$1` in the block given to it.

I point out the statement in the [section of Regular expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#class-Regexp-label-3D~+operator) of Ruby's official document (Ver.2.5.1)

> Using `=~` operator with a String and Regexp the `$~` global variable is set after a successful match.

is rather misleading, because

1. `$~` is a *pre-defined local-scope* variable (**not** global variable), and
2. `$~` is set (maybe nil) regardless of whether the last attempted match is successful or not.

The fact the variables like `$~` and `$1` are not global variables may be slightly confusing.  But hey, they are useful notations, aren't they?