# Will a block open another thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, global-variables

This question comes from this code snippet:

```
lambda do
  $SAFE = 2
  puts $SAFE
end .call

puts $SAFE
```

The result is:

```
2
0
```

`$SAFE` is a global variable, so I can't understand this. I explored it for a while, and then found `$SAFE` is a thread-local variable, not a real global.

OK, I can understand this:

```
k = Thread.new do
  $SAFE = 2
  puts $SAFE
end

k.run

1000000.times {}

puts $SAFE
```

But wait, the block will open another thread to run it?

Comment: It does not open another thread to run it. Try for yourself: `Thread.current.object_id == lambda { Thread.current.object_id }.call`. Since the whole purpose of `$SAFE` seems to be the implementation of sandboxes etc. it sounds natural to me, that the value is not only thread-local, but also block-local.

Comment: I can't test with `$SAFE` (warning: SAFE levels are not supported in JRuby), but `lambda {sleep 5; puts "inside"}.call; puts "outside"` yields the expected result (delay, inside, outside). If anything, this is `$SAFE` magic.

Comment: @platzhirsch, is there really block-local global variable? I can't find any documentation on this. Can you give some?

Comment: @SefierTang I am afraid you won't find any documentation on this. Also see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278454/setting-a-global-within-a-proc

Comment: @platzhirsch, I got it. Thank you. Could you post an answer so I can adopt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, blocks (procs, lambdas) do not run in their own threads. The issue here is that Ruby saves and restores the `$SAFE` level around each and every method (and proc) call. If you try this with another variable, like `$FOO`, you get the expected results:

```
> x = ->{ $FOO = 1; puts $FOO }.call; puts $FOO
1
1
```

You can see where this is implemented in `rb_method_call` in `proc.c`:

```
const int safe_level_to_run = 4 /*SAFE_LEVEL_MAX*/;
safe = rb_safe_level();
if (rb_safe_level() < safe_level_to_run) {
    rb_set_safe_level_force(safe_level_to_run);
}

// ...
// Invoke the block
// ...

if (safe >= 0)
  rb_set_safe_level_force(safe);
```

The safe level is saved, and if it's less than 4, it's set to 4. The block is then called, and if the safe level before modification was >= 0, it's restored to what it was before. You can see this in action with something like the following:

```
> puts $SAFE; ->{ puts $SAFE; $SAFE = 1; puts $SAFE }.call; puts $SAFE
0
0
1
0
```

`$SAFE` is 0 heading into the block, and the block is executed, and then it's restored to 0 as the block exits, despite being modified to be 1 inside the block.